# Rails occasionally freezes after HTML POST - Extremely Long Active Record Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, post, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 4 application that will occasionally freeze for as much as 5 minutes at a time, leaving the website inaccessible to anyone. Occasionally when a HTTP POST originating from /plays is started, the server will completely lock up and become unresponsive.

According to this source below, ActiveRecord should be used sparingly as well as reducing the use of .all with find_in_batches

https://chaione.com/blog/dealing-massive-data-rails/ActiveRecord

My suspicion was that set_plays in PlaysController may have been the culprit but now I am leaning more towards the misuse of rails cache feature, as this issue occurs at irregular intervals and is difficult to reproduce.

Below is a snippet from the plays controller.

```
class PlaysController < ApplicationController
  helper PlaysHelper
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :set_plays, only: [:index, :create]
  before_action :set_play, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html, :json

  layout "layouts/tabs"

  before_filter :title
  before_filter :set_links

  def new
    @play = Play.new
    respond_with(@play)
  end

  def create
    @play = Play.new(play_params)
    @play.show ||= @play.get_show(current_user)
    if pbn = params[:playbox_number]
      @play.playbox_number = pbn
    end
    if @play.save
      begin
        report_play_to_shoutcast(@play) if Rails.env.production?
      rescue StandardError => e
        flash[:error] = "Unable to report play to SHOUTcast #{e.inspect}\n#{e.backtrace[0]}"
      end
      begin
        report_play_to_tunein(@play) if Rails.env.production?
      rescue StandardError => e
        flash[:error] = "Unable to report play to tunein #{e.inspect}\n#{e.backtrace[0]}"
      end
      # clear the cache of anything with play information in it
      clear_plays_cache
      # go ahead and reset the last_play cache, because we already have the value in hand
      set_last_play(@play)
      @play = Play.new
      render(action: :index)
    else
      respond_with(@play)
    end
  end

  private
    def set_play
      @play = Play.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_plays
      @plays = Play.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50, total_entries: plays_count() ).order('created_at DESC').preload(:show,:playbox)
    end

    def play_params
      params.require(:play).permit(:artist, :album, :track, :show_id)
    end
end
```

And a portion of the application helper

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def set_last_play(play)
    Rails.cache.write("plays__last_play", play, expires_in: 5.minutes, race_condition_ttl: 10.seconds)
  end # set_last_play

  def last_play
    @last_play ||= Rails.cache.fetch("plays__last_play", expires_in: 5.minutes, race_condition_ttl: 10.seconds) do
        Play.order("created_at").includes(:show).last || Play.new(album: "", artist: "", track: "", show: nil)
    end
  end # last_play

  def plays_count
    # only one 1 underscore (_) in order to avoid being eliminated by clear_plays_cache
    @plays_count ||= Rails.cache.fetch("plays_count", expires_in: 5.hours, race_condition_ttl: 10.seconds) do
        Play.count
    end
  end

  def clear_plays_cache
    Rails.cache.delete_matched('plays__')
  end # clear_plays_cache
end
```

Here is an example of the issue from the logfile

```
I, [2019-06-19T08:25:37.659021 #5772]  INFO -- : Started POST "/plays" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-06-19 08:25:37 -0400
I, [2019-06-19T08:25:37.659021 #5772]  INFO -- : Processing by PlaysController#create as HTML
I, [2019-06-19T08:25:37.659021 #5772]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"REDACTED", "playbox_number"=>"", "play"=>{"artist"=>"Band", "track"=>"Song", "album"=>"Single", "show_id"=>"720"}, "commit"=>"Create Play"}
I, [2019-06-19T08:26:07.209014 #5772]  INFO -- :   Rendered plays/_playbox_requirements.html.erb (15.7ms)
I, [2019-06-19T08:26:07.209014 #5772]  INFO -- :   Rendered plays/_form.html.erb (15.7ms)
I, [2019-06-19T08:26:07.255871 #5772]  INFO -- :   Rendered plays/_table.html.erb (46.9ms)
I, [2019-06-19T08:26:07.255871 #5772]  INFO -- :   Rendered plays/index.html.erb within layouts/tabs (62.5ms)
I, [2019-06-19T08:26:07.255871 #5772]  INFO -- :   Rendered plays/_lastwidget.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2019-06-19T08:26:07.255871 #5772]  INFO -- :   Rendered application/_login.overlay.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2019-06-19T08:26:07.255871 #5772]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/application.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2019-06-19T08:26:07.255871 #5772]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/bootstrap.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2019-06-19T08:26:07.255871 #5772]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/bootstrap-wide.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2019-06-19T08:26:07.255871 #5772]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 276754ms (Views: 66.8ms | ActiveRecord: 35996.5ms)
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling the cache to eliminate that as a probable cause? Rails 4 is no longer supported, so if this is a bug that's been fixed in a subsequent release it may be worth updating to find out, depending on how complex and difficult it is to upgrade.

Comment: Why filter 'set_plays' before create action is needed?